# Symmetry group of a non abelian group manifold

Tags: group-theory, manifolds

Reading an article

> ...$B$ is itself the manifold of some group $H$. It should be noted that, if $H$ is a non abelian group, the symmetry group $G$ of the group manifold is not $H$ but $H\times{}H$, since the group manifold can be transformed by either left or right multiplication.

I don't get the left or right argument

Answer (score 3):

First, a caveat: The "symmetry group of a manifold" is not, by itself, a well-defined concept.  Without some further structure on the manifold, the only groups that are completely determined by the manifold are infinite-dimensional ones such as its diffeomorphism group or homeomorphism group.  In order to identify a finite-dimensional "symmetry group," you have to say what you want the group action to preserve -- should it preserve a Riemannian or pseudo-Riemannian metric?  Or a Lie group structure? Or a symplectic structure? Or something else?

With that in mind, what seems to be going on here is this: If $H$ is any Lie group, then there's a natural action of $H\times H$ on itself by left and right multiplication:
$$(h_1,h_2)\centerdot h = (h_1)h(h_2)^{-1}.$$
But depending on the group, this action might or might not be *effective* (meaning that only the identity of $H\times H$ acts trivially on $H$).  In the special case in which $H$ is abelian, then every element of the diagonal subgroup $\Delta = \{(h,h): h\in H\}$ acts trivially, so in fact this is more properly considered as an action of the quotient group $(H\times H)/\Delta$.  This group is isomorphic to $H$ itself, and its action on $H$ is equivalent to the left action given by $h_1\centerdot h = h_1 h$.  This seems to be the sense in which the article is considering the symmetry group to be $H$ in the abelian case and $H\times H$ otherwise.  But this is not really correct either, because for some nonabelian groups there will still be elements of $H\times H$ that act trivially (the subgroup of $\Delta$ consisting of central elements of the group), so the "symmetry group" in general might be some quotient of $H\times H$.

In what sense is this "the symmetry group of $H$"?  There's not enough information to say. If $H$ is endowed with a bi-invariant metric, then the action of $H\times H$ (or whatever quotient of it acts effectively) preserves that metric. But not every Lie group has a bi-invariant metric.  On the other hand, every Lie group does have a *left-invariant* metric, but that will typically be preserved by $H\times \{\text{Id}\}$, not in general by all of $H\times H$.

You could also ask about group actions that preserve the Lie group structure of $H$ -- the *automorphism group* of $H$.  But this isn't it.  It is true that the subgroup $\Delta$ acts on $H$ by automorphisms (conjugation), but that might not be the entire automorphism group. (The automorphisms in $\Delta$ are called *inner automorphisms*, and the other ones are *outer*.)

So the bottom line is that you have to read further in the article to figure out what "symmetry group" the author is talking about.